# Cygwin: Command works on the console, not in a .bat

Tags: command-line, bash, cygwin

This command works in the Cygwin console:

```
me@WDX5CG625Q ~
$ cd "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.5"

mw@WDX5CG62Q /cygdrive/c/Program Files/apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.5
$
```

But not in a .bat file:

tom.bat:

```
cd "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.5"
```

output:

```
me@WDX5CG625Q ~
$ ./tom.bat

C:\cygwin64\home\me>cd "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.5"
The system cannot find the path specified.

me@WDX5CG625Q ~
$
```

Also tried:

- With a `#!/bin/bash`
- Without quotes
- Without quotes and spaces escaped
- With quotes and spaces escaped

Always get the “cannot find” message.

Comment: The working version has "apache" with a small "a"; the failing version has a capital "A". Unix file names are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a `.BAT` file from Cygwin, it runs as a batch file,
using the Windows command interpreter (`CMD.EXE`, a.k.a. “Command Prompt”). 
So

- If you want to run a batch file, using primarily Windows CLI commands,
  use the Windows version of the pathname: `C:\Program Files\apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5`. 
  It’s probably OK if you use `/` instead of `\`,
  just as it is in an ordinary Windows Command Prompt. 
  Don’t worry about case.
- If you want to run a Unix shell script, don’t use the `.BAT` extension.